# Count the number of spaces between words in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, whitespace, spaces

I am doing [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/capitalize) problem on Hackerrank,and I came up with the idea, which includes splitting the input and join it afterwards (see my implementation below).  However, one of the test cases contains the input (**hello**< multiple spaces> **world**), which crashed my code because the input string has more than 1 space between each words.  So, I am just wondering if anyone could please help me out fix my code, and I am just wondering how to count how many spaces(esp multiple spaces) in a string in Python.  I found how to count spaces in Java, but not in Python.  For testcase, I attached the pic.

Thanks in advance.

***My implementation:***

```
input_string = input()

splitter = input_string.split()

final = []

for i in range(0,len(splitter)):
    for j in range(0,len(splitter[i])):
        if(j==0):
            final.append(splitter[i][j].upper())
        else:
            final.append(splitter[i][j])
    # Assumed that there is one space btw each words
    final.append(' ')
print(''.join(final))
```

> For Test case pic,

[image]

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to do. Do you just need to count the number of whitespace characters in the string?

Comment: If you just want to count the number of whitespaces in string, you can do `input_string.count(' ')`

Comment: Having more than one space shouldn't be a problem when you use `split`. I am not sure if I understand the problem.

Comment: Trying to find the number of spaces is a bad start for that question.

Comment: First, I wanna thank you guys for your feedback. 
What I am having trouble is that my implementation doesn't work when there is two spaces between each words in a string(as you can see in the test case: **"hello_ _world lol"**. The reason behind is that I used string.split(), which removes all of the spaces, so there is no way I can check how many spaces between each words when I join them back. So, I didn't pass the test case. So, I want to know if there is anyway that can fix my code to pass the testcase. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it by splitting with pattern `' '` (whitespace)

```
splitter = input_string.split(' ')
```

You can also use .capitalize() method instead of splitting the token again

```
s = "hello  world         4lol"
a = s.split(' ')

new_string = ''
for i in range(0, len(a)) :
   new_string = a[i].capitalize() if len(new_string)==0 else new_string +' '+ a[i].capitalize()
print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
Hello  World         4lol
```

For counting number of spaces between two words, you can use python's regular expressions module.

```
import re    
s = "hello       world  loL"
tokens = re.findall('\s+', s)

for i in range(0, len(tokens)) :
    print(len(tokens[i]))
```

Output :

```
7
2
```

Comment: @ArashHatami for counting the spaces, solution is already provided in one of the other post, basically you can count all the zero length consecutive tokens after splitting that will give you the count of spaces between two words.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as asked

Comment: @Nighthacks Thanks for your help. First time seeing how to use RE module to solve this problem.  I do not use that module because it is kind of confusing and hard to understand.  But, in this case, using findall from RE module solve this problem easily.  Thanks for your time and explanation !

Comment: @harrisonthu, for the tutorial question, you don't need to count spaces, just use the other two approaches, either use .capitalize() or add a pattern whitespace while splitting. :)

Comment: @harrisonthu, using .title() alone will fail in the cases where any word starts with a number (assuming you only want to capitalize the first letter).

Comment: @Nighthacks Yes, you are correct, .title() alone will fail the test case, such as ("1 w 2 r 3g").  According to your suggestion, I implement using capitalize, and it works !  Thank you so much for your help.   :)

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest doing for the tutorial question is a quick simple solution.

```
s = input()
print(s.title())
```

`str.title()` will capitalise the starting letter of every word in a string.

---

Now to answer the question for counting spaces you can use `str.count())` which will take a string and return the number of occurrences it finds.

```
s = 'Hello    World'
s.count(' ')
```

There are various other methods as well, such as:

```
s = input()
print(len(s) - len(''.join(s.split())))

s2 = input()
print(len(s2) - len(s2.replace(' ', '')))
```

However count is easiest to implement and follow.

Now, count will return the total number, if you're after the number of spaces between each world.

Then something like this should suffice

```
s = input()

spaces = []
counter = 0
for char in s:
    if char== ' ':
        counter += 1
    elif counter != 0:
        spaces.append(counter)
        counter = 0

print(spaces)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! @steven.  I am surprised to see that just s.title() will solve this problem  :)

Comment: @StevenSummers An up vote, for a) following the link to discover the actual issue and b) providing the simplest, cleanest solution using `.title()`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re    
line = "Hello    World  LoL"
total = 0
for spl in re.findall('\s+', line):
    print len(spl)
    total += len(spl) # 4, 2
print total # 6

>>> 4
>>> 2
>>> 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation !  That is pretty neat.  I have never used regular expression before, so this is my first time learning how to count spaces using RE module. :)

Answer (score 1):

For you problem with spaces

```
my_string = "hello    world"
spaces = 0
for elem in my_string:
    if elem == " ":
    #space between quotes
    spaces += 1
print(spaces)
```

Comment: Thanks for your implementation.  That works correctly for counting how many spaces **between two words**.  However, in the worst scenarios, lets say the input is constructed with 3 words with different spaces, such as "hello   world  lol", so I'd like to know how to keep track of spaces between each words in the input string.  For the given input, it would be 3 spaces between "hello" and "world" and two for "world" and "lol" words.  Then, I need to capitalize the first word then, depending on the spaces, I need to print the count between each words.

Answer (score 0):

you can use count() function to count repeat of a special character

```
string_name.count('character')
```

for count space you should :

```
input_string = input()
splitter = input_string.split()
final = []
for i in range(0, len(splitter)):
    for j in range(0, len(splitter[i])):
        if(j==0):
            final.append(splitter[i][j].upper())
        else:
            final.append(splitter[i][j])
    final.append(' ')
count = input_string.count(' ')
print(''.join(final))
print (count)
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Forget the spaces they are not your problem.
You can reduce the string to just the words without the extra spaces using `split(None)` which will give you a word count and your string i.e.

```
>>> a = "   hello  world         lol"
>>> b = a.split(None)
>>> len(b)
3
>>> print(" ".join(b))
hello world lol
```

Edit: After following your link to read the actual question, next time include the relevant details in your question, it makes it easier all round,
your issue still isn't counting the number of spaces, before, between or after the words. The answer that solves the specific task has already been provided, in the form of:

```
>>> a= " hello    world  42  lol"
>>> a.title()
' Hello    World  42  Lol'
>>>
```

See the answer provided by @Steven Summers

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your clarification.  However, I am currently looking for a way to count spaces between each words in a string (as @ArashHatami mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem a time ago, just add " " (white space) to the split function and then print each element separated by a white space. Thats all.

```
for i in input().split(" "):
    print(i.capitalize(), end=" ")
```

The result of the split function with "hello    world    lol" is

```
>>> "hello    world    lol".split(" ")
>>>['hello', '', '', '', 'world', '', '', '', 'lol']
```

Then print each element + a white space.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach**

---

Given a string, the task is to count the number of spaces between words in a string.

**Example:**

```
Input: "my name  is geeks for geeks"
Output: Spaces b/w "my" and "name": 1
        Spaces b/w "name" and "is": 2
        Spaces b/w "is" and "geeks": 1
        Spaces b/w "geeks" and "for": 1
        Spaces b/w "for" and "geeks": 1

Input: "heyall"
Output: No spaces
```

**Steps to be performed**

---

- Input string from the user’s and strip the string for the removing unused spaces.
- Initialize an empty list
- Run a for loop from 0 till the length of the string
- Inside for loop, store all the words without spaces
- Again Inside for loop, for storing the actual Indexes of the words.
- Outside for loop, print the number of spaces b/w words.

Below is the implementation of the above approach:

```
# Function to find spaces b/w each words
def Spaces(Test_string):
    Test_list = []  # Empty list
    
    # Remove all the spaces and append them in a list
    for i in range(len(Test_string)):
        if Test_string[i] != "":
            Test_list.append(Test_string[i])
            
    Test_list1=Test_list[:]
    
    # Append the exact position of the words in a Test_String
    for j in range(len(Test_list)):
        Test_list[j] = Test_string.index(Test_list[j])
        Test_string[j] = None
        
    # Finally loop for printing the spaces b/w each words.
    for i in range(len(Test_list)):
        if i+1 < len(Test_list):
            print(
                f"Spaces b/w \"{Test_list1[i]}\" and \"{Test_list1[i+1]}\": {Test_list[i+1]-Test_list[i]}")

# Driver function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test_string = input("Enter a String: ").strip() # Taking string as input
    
    Test_string = Test_string.split(" ")  # Create string into list
    
    if len(Test_string)==1:
        print("No Spaces")
    else:
        Spaces(Test_string)  # Call function
```

Comment: Are you sure, that your answer is better than the ones already provided? If you think it is, please make your intentions clearer and more easily understandable.

Comment: OK, Thank you, I'll do it.